# Leer ultima linea en Python

Tags: python, txt

Estoy leyendo un txt en Python tratanto de contar cuantas líneas hay en blanco, pero la ultima línea no la cuenta. Es decir a partir de un txt así leer cuantas están en blanco:

```
1. a
2. 
3. b
4. 
5. c
6.
(Sin poner los números)
```

El codigo que utilizo es este... ¿Cómo puedo forzar a leer dicha línea?

```
with open("txt", "r") as f:
   for linea in f:
      if linea.strip() == ''
         count += 1
```

PD: Me gustaría mantener esa estructura porque el problema general no es ese.

Comment: Tomando ese ejemplo, la salida de tu programa es ¿3 o 5?. Una manera de "forzar" es evitar el uso de `linea.strip()` puesto que esa línea es la que está evitando que obtengas las líneas vacias en el conteo.

Comment: Tu código cuenta bien las líneas en blanco. Tal vez el problema está en el archivo de texto. Puede que no tenga una último línea en blanco. Revisa el contenido del archivo por otro medio, como 'wc' o un hexdump.